# Are ruby regular expressios the right way to go?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working on a linguistics project in which I need to search for patterns within a text. I need to search for the following pattern: `„ blah blah blah **target word** blah blah"`. In other words, instances of a particular word contained within (German) quotation marks where there can be any number of other words between the quotation marks.

The software I use says that it is written in Ruby and it uses regular expressions to be matched against. I need to know whether they are the right tool for the job.  Is this the kind of pattern that Ruby regular expressions can capture?

Comment: The ruby regex flavor has a few additional twists, but you'll find an excellent overview of what can be done using regular expressions over at http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: just discovered this. Excellent resource.

Comment: Your closing mark is not a typographic quotation mark (`“`) but a straight quotation mark (`"`).

Comment: Become familiar with http://rubular.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Given that you have a string in `target_word`, the following will do.

```
/\„.*?#{target_word}.*?\"/m
```

You might need special consideration for German quotes though.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start (German quotes are giving me trouble, as predicted). I'll try to figure out the rest now that I know it is possible, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you indeed need regular expressions or [tokenization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization)

I'd go with the latter if you have no experience with programming, regular expressions are quite hard to master.

Comment: The thing is regular expressions are accepted by the software that I use which is how I ended up here.